# Show image string-resource (xml) android

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

How can I show an image in a string-array, in xml-format in android?

```
     <string-array name = "cities_info"> 
    <item>
        <![CDATA[<i><b>Image1:</b> Map of Africa. 
          Cape Town (Afrikaans: Kaapstad [ˈkɑːpstɐt]; Xhosa: Ikapa) is a
          city in South Africa. It ranks third among the most populous urban areas in South Africa, after Johannesburg and Durban, and has roughly the
          same population as the Durban Metropolitan Area. It is also 
          the provincial capital and primate city of the Western Cape
        ]]>
    </item>
```

I have tried with html-code but it doesnt work

```
<img src="capetown.jpg" alt="city" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
```

or

```
 <img src="@drawable/capetown.jpg" alt="city" style="width:300px height:300px;">
```

Comment: @MukeshRana - Yes, thats correct :-)

Comment: You can't use image like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) for that in `array.xml` file within your `res/values` folder to create an array of other resources, such as drawables

Your xml will look like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="cities_images">
        <item>@drawable/capetown</item>
        <item>@drawable/newyork</item>
        <item>@drawable/losangeles</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and your Activity code will be something like this

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.cities_images);

// get resource ID by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));

// recycle the array
imgs.recycle();
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to integrate the image ( a small image) in the text itself. Not an array with images.

Comment: AFAIK I don't think that can be possible